# compare time values and datetimeindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time

I got two time strings.  and a pandas datetimeindex

```
t1 = "08:45:00"
t2 ="17:30:00"



#idx = 
pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-06-17 08:45:00', '2019-06-17 08:46:00', '2019-06-17 08:47:00', '2019-06-17 08:48:00', '2019-06-17 08:49:00', '2019-06-17 08:50:00', '2019-06-17 08:51:00',
... 
 '2019-06-17 08:52:00', '2019-06-17 08:53:00', '2019-06-17 08:54:00', '2019-08-20 11:51:00', '2019-08-20 11:52:00', '2019-08-20 11:53:00', '2019-08-20 11:54:00', 
'2019-08-20 11:55:00', '2019-08-20 11:56:00', '2019-08-20 11:57:00', '2019-08-20 11:58:00', '2019-08-20 11:59:00', '2019-08-20 12:00:00'],
 dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=66436, freq=None)
```

everytime i convert them this way :

```
 t1 =   pd.to_datetime( pd.Series(t1)[0],format='%H:%M:%S').time

 t2 =   pd.to_datetime( pd.Series(t1)[0],format='%H:%M:%S').time
```

and then try to compare it via:

```
temp_idx     = pd.Series(idx.time, index=index)
temp_idx     = temp_idx.loc[(temp_idx>=t1) & (temp_idx<=t2)]
```

(or even without the pd.Series()[0] it wont work.

Instead I get this in the comparison line:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

It sees the time as a 'builtin_function_or_method'.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the entire error Traceback

Comment: `TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'length'`

Comment: Please fix your minimal, reproducible example. It results in errors.